# Crystal Reports Multiple if conditions in Record Selection

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-xi

I want to create a report and filter it by two parameters as below;

Parameter values are;

```
Call_type = "All" , "Sale" , "Buy"
and
Call_status = "All" , "Sold" , "Pending" , "None" , "Closed"
```

I have used below formula;

```
(
if {?type} <> "All" then
    {cars_call_log.type} = {?type}
else
    true;
);
(
if {?status} <> "All" then
    {cars_call_log.status} = {?status}
else
    true;
);
```

But it will work only for first If condition. It doesn't work for both conditions.

I want to make it like, Filter by first parameter then (filtered records)--> filter by second parameter.

Comment: You are adding to individual instructions, rather than a single, compound instruction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The proper, record-selection-formula syntax for your needs:

```
(
if {?type} <> "All" then
  {cars_call_log.type} = {?type}
else
  true
)
AND
(
if {?status} <> "All" then
  {cars_call_log.status} = {?status}
else
  true
)
```

Comment: Code dumps are not answers.  Please update your answer to include a description of what this code is, what differs from the original source, and what the changes do that fix the problem.